# Is gnuplot able to summarize x rows as a single data point?

Tags: gnuplot

The question is if I can change the resolution of the data in gnuplot easily.

Say I have a N+1 column file consisting of x and y1, y2, ... ,yN values.
X datapoints have a resolution of one minute.

What I like to do is setting a parameter (say 5) and now gnuplot calculates a datapoint out of the first 5 rows for all y columns, then the second five rows and so on (means: take first x value and for every y column sum them up for a 5 row interval divided by 5).

Is this possible without changing the datafile itself? Maybe there exists already such a feature? Or do you think it is a more elegant way manipulating the datafile?

Thx for your thoughts.

Comment: How large is N? Just 2,3 or 5 or 20,50,100? Are the x intervals regular or irregular?

Comment: @theozh N = 13 and x intervals are irregular? I can manipulate the datafile for my needs but I would like to know if gnuplot's capabilities are more efficient or easier to use. So the question is a bit broader. THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  However it is a bit complicated in the general case, so you might prefer to do the averaging in a separate preprocessing step before passing the data to gnuplot.

First note that you can create a filter to accept and plot every Nth point by using the pseudo-column 0 (line number) and the "not a number" flag NaN.  The `+1` is because the line numbering starts at zero.

```
filter(y) = ((int(column(0)+1)%N == 0) ? y : NaN)
plot DATA using 1:(filter(column(2)))
```

Now we make the filter more complicated by adding a serial evaluation operator to each of the two outcome paths.  Serial evaluation guarantees that comma-separated expressions are evaluated in left-to-right order with the net value set to the value of the rightmost expression.

```
sum_and_filter(y) = (int(column(0)+1)%N == 0) ? (out=(sum+y)/N, sum=0, out) : (sum=sum+y, NaN)
sum = 0
plot DATA using 1:(sum_and_filter(column(2)))
```

Here is a plot showing both the original data and the output from filtering

```
N = 5
sum = 0
plot DATA using 1:2 with linespoints pt 1, \
     DATA using 1:(sum_and_filter(column(2))) with points pt 7
```

[image]

In the special case that your x values are equally spaced, a much simpler option is available since gnuplot version 5.2.something.  The keyword `bins` will do the accumulation for you. However left to itself it will plot the sum rather than the mean of the bin contents, so you need prior knowledge of the x spacing to calculate the mean. Here I add the bin option to the previous plot.  Note that it does not use the filtering function at all.

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.25
plot DATA using 1:2 with linespoints pt 1, \
     DATA using 1:(sum_and_filter(column(2))) with points pt 7, \
     DATA using 1:($2/5) bins binwidth=50 with boxes title "bin width 50"
```

[image]

The bins are drawn centered about the corresponding range of x values.  You might want to adjust this by including an offset:  `plot DATA using ($1-offset):($2/5)`.

Comment: This looks very promissing and both methods are new to me. Thx a lot for taking time to answer in such a nice and clear way. I just have to see how to handle irregular x axis datapoints, which was not mentioned in my question ;)